# Sporadic timeout failures when using Akka Streams testkit

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, akka-stream

I have some strange behavior that I am seeing whenever I try to use the Streams testkit from Akka.

I do have the following custom defined:

```
trait PauseFilter[T] {

  def shouldPause(message: T): Boolean
}

trait MessagePauser[T] {

  def pause(message: T): Unit
}

trait MessageUnPauser[T] {

  def unPause: Option[T]
}

object PausableFlow {

  def pausableFlow[T](filter: PauseFilter[T], pauser: MessagePauser[T], unpauser: MessageUnPauser[T]): Flow[T, T, _] =

    Flow.fromGraph(
      GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        val initialMessagesIn = builder.add(Flow[T])
        val finalMessagesOut = builder.add(Flow[T])
        val unPauserIterator = () => Iterator.continually(unpauser.unPause)
        val unpausedMessages = Source.fromIterator(unPauserIterator).collect { case Some(m) => m }
        val pausedMessagesSink = Sink.foreach(pauser.pause)
        val determineIfPaused = builder.add(Partition[T](2, message => if (filter.shouldPause(message)) 1 else 0))
        val merge = builder.add(Merge[T](2))

        unpausedMessages    ~>    merge
        initialMessagesIn   ~>    merge   ~>    determineIfPaused
                                                determineIfPaused.out(1)    ~>    pausedMessagesSink
                                                determineIfPaused.out(0)    ~>    finalMessagesOut

        FlowShape(initialMessagesIn.in, finalMessagesOut.out)
      }
    )
}
```

In addition to that I have defined the following sanity check test in the spec of the flow:

```
test("a pauser that pauses half the messages should propagate only half the messages and pause the other half") {
  val filter = new PauseFilter[Int] {
    override def shouldPause(m: Int): Boolean = if (m % 2 == 0) true else false
  }

  val unpauser = mock[MessageUnPauser[Int]]
  Mockito.when(unpauser.unPause).thenReturn(None)

  val pauser = mock[MessagePauser[Int]]

  val (pub, sub) = getTestHandles(PausableFlow.pausableFlow[Int](filter, pauser, unpauser))

  sub.request(200)
  1 to 100 foreach pub.sendNext
  1 to 100 filter (m => m % 2 == 1) foreach sub.expectNext
  1 to 100 filter (m => m % 2 == 0) foreach Mockito.verify(pauser, Mockito.times(1)).pause
}

private def getTestHandles[T](flow: Flow[T, T, _]) = 
  TestSource.probe[T]
    .via(flow)
    .toMat(TestSink.probe[T])(Keep.both)
    .run()
```

What is happening is that I get sporadic failures with the following exception:

```
assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg: 
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg: 
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
  at akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:405)
  at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:814)
  at akka.stream.testkit.StreamTestKit$PublisherProbeSubscription.expectRequest(StreamTestKit.scala:716)
  at akka.stream.testkit.TestPublisher$Probe.sendNext(StreamTestKit.scala:173)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(PausableFlowSpec.scala:70)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(PausableFlowSpec.scala:70)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(PausableFlowSpec.scala:70)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(PausableFlowSpec.scala:57)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec$$anonfun$3.apply(PausableFlowSpec.scala:57)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:166)
  at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:1555)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:163)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTest(FunSuite.scala:1555)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:1555)
  at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1555)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
  at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
  at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(PausableFlowSpec.scala:16)
  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:257)
  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:256)
  at com.company.stream.pausable.PausableFlowSpec.run(PausableFlowSpec.scala:16)
  at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

I have left some of the code out so just to give you a reference point so you can tie the exception to the actual code. The exception is thrown when `1 to 100 foreach pub.sendNext` is invoked. I am quite perplexed as to why this happens as there is nothing that is so time consuming of an operation to cause such behavior. Maybe I am missing something here. Will be great to get your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in `unPausedMessages` - this kills (performance wise) the stream. Consider taming this calls with:

```
val unpausedMessages = Source
  .tick(FiniteDuration(0, "ms"), FiniteDuration(100, "ms"), unpauser.unPause)
  .collect { case Some(m) => m }
```

or equivalent.

Other thing that happens, is that you try to push to many items into stream without consuming.
Consider running `1 to 100 foreach pub.sendNext` inside a `Future` that executes concurrently to consumers.